# Get random row from table when generating new table

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-scripts

I have table `categories` with columns `category_id` and `name`. I want to generate new table `products` with random data. Table `products` has columns `product_id, category_id, name, price`. I want to give to each product random `category_id`.

My generate script for table `products`:

```
INSERT INTO products (category_id, name, price) 
SELECT
   (SELECT category_id FROM categories OFFSET floor(random()*50) LIMIT 1),
   ('Product ' || i),
   round(cast(random() * 999 + 1 as numeric), 2)
FROM generate_series(1,100) as seq(i)
```

This script generate 100 rows of products, but each product has the same `category_id`. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is that Postgres is too aggressive about optimization.  It is able to recognize that the subquery could be called just once -- somehow ignoring the fact that `random()` is not a deterministic function.

One method to fix this involves a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT (SELECT category_id
        FROM categories c
        WHERE c.category_id <> seq.i
        OFFSET floor(random()*3)
        LIMIT 1
       ),
       ('Product ' || i),
       round(cast(random() * 999 + 1 as numeric), 2)
FROM generate_series(1,100) as seq(i);
```